# Insert caption and button in the same bootstrap caroussel

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to move buttons "Télécharger l'appli" and "Mode d'emploi" just above my caroussel indicators.

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="row">
        <!-- Caroussel
        ================================================== -->
        <div id="monCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicateurs -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#monCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#monCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Diapositives -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/gps.jpg" alt="gps">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        =========my issue=========
                        <h3>Consulter facilement votre agenda</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="testAndroid()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> Télécharger l'appli</button>
                        <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="https://blabla.fr" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Mode d'emploi</a>
                        ==================
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="prise de photo">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        =========my issue=========
                        <h3>Test 2</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="testAndroid()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> Télécharger l'appli</button>
                        <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="https://blabla.fr" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Mode d'emploi</a>
                        ==================
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Flèches de contrôle -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#monCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#monCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Actual result : https://www.noelshack.com/2019-28-5-1562884515-capture.png
Result expected : https://www.noelshack.com/2019-28-5-1562884817-expectedresult.png

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you change the class `.item` to `.carousel-item` and remove the `.row`:

```html
<div class="container">
    <!-- Caroussel
  ================================================== -->
    <div id="monCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicateurs -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators" />
        <!-- Diapositives -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    =========my issue=========
                    <h3>Consulter facilement votre agenda</h3>
                    <button />
                    <a type="button" />
                    ==================
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    =========my issue=========
                    <h3>Test 2</h3>
                    <button />
                    <a type="button" />
                    ==================
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Flèches de contrôle -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#monCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#monCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/dso1cx9q/12/

Comment: Thanks David for your reply